# Finding pairs that share commonalities in ORACLE DB

Tags: sql, database, oracle, relational-database

so I'm currently struggling with the above mentioned task (University assignment).

I need to find pairs of people (p1.LASTNAME,p2.LASTNAME) that have the same favourite cocktail and also attended the same event at least once.

The required Oracle tables are PERSON and VISITED and they look like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE PERSON
(
    PID      INT,
    FIRSTNAME  VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
    LASTNAME VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
    FAVCOCKTAIL INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (PID),
    FOREIGN KEY (FAVCOCKTAIL) REFERENCES COCKTAIL (CID)
);

CREATE TABLE VISITED
(
    PID INT,
    VID INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (PID) REFERENCES PERSON (PID),
    FOREIGN KEY (VID) REFERENCES VISITED (VID)
);
```

This has been my approach so far:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT P1.LASTNAME, P2.LASTNAME, B1.VID, B2.VID, P1.FAVCOCKTAIL, P2.FAVCOCKTAIL
FROM PERSON P1,
     PERSON P2,
     VISITED B1,
     VISITED B2
WHERE P1.FAVCOCKTAIL = P2.FAVCOCKTAIL
  AND B1.VID = B2.VID
  AND P1.LASTNAME != P2.LASTNAME;
```

Now whenever I read "at least once" I'm thinking of using the COUNT function which I tried but I can't get it to work, same goes for several JOIN-Methods which I've tried.

I'm sure that there is an elegant solution to this problem. My approach feels more like "brute force" in some sense.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `JOIN`. `JOIN`. `JOIN`.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Besides using the outdated syntax of implicit joins instead of using an explicit `join` clause, I don't see a problem with your solution. Is it actually generating the wrong results?

Comment: Sample data would help a lot.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've never liked building the cartesian product by using comma separation since it produces so many redundant data sets but that's how we learned in Uni but thank you for your answer I didn't know you could use JOIN like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for simplicity (and sample data within the CTE I'm going to post later, as you didn't provide any), I'm creating a simple view which joins people and places they visited (changing VID to something *readable*):

```
create or replace view v_view as
  select p.pid, p.lastname, p.favcocktail, v.vid
  from person p join visited v on v.pid = p.pid;
```

Then, if you do something like this, you might get the result:

```
SQL> with v_view (pid, lastname, favcocktail, vid) as
  2    (select 1, 'Scott', 'Pepsi', 'London' from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'King' , 'Pepsi', 'London' from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'Mike' , '7up'  , 'London' from dual union all
  5     select 4, 'John' , 'Pepsi', 'Paris'  from dual
  6    )
  7  select listagg(a.lastname, ', ') within group (order by null) people,
  8         a.favcocktail,
  9         a.visited
 10  from v_view a join v_view b on a.pid <> b.pid
 11    and a.favcocktail = b.favcocktail
 12    and a.vid = b.vid
 13  group by a.favcocktail,
 14           a.visited;

PEOPLE                         FAVCOCKTAIL     VID
------------------------------ --------------- ---------------
King, Scott                    Pepsi           London

SQL>
```

---

Or, without sample data and view moved into a CTE (so that you could execute it right away):

```
with v_view as
  (select p.pid, p.lastname, p.favcocktail, v.vid
   from person p join visited v on v.pid = p.pid
  )
select listagg(a.lastname, ', ') within group (order by null) people, 
       a.favcocktail, 
       a.vid
from v_view a join v_view b on a.pid <> b.pid
  and a.favcocktail = b.favcocktail
  and a.vid = b.vid
group by a.favcocktail,
         a.vid;
```